# Angular UI Router with ng-enter-stagger

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I hope someone can help me I have been stuck on this for a while.

I have a simple jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mcneela86/aodsux3p/
Which is using the `ng-enter-stagger` class to stagger the animations on each list item, and it seems to work fine.

I have then tried to use this method with an app built on the ui-router but the animation is not working: http://plnkr.co/edit/IDpTQuwELq0zWsqMDrPw?p=preview

Am I doing something wrong or does this method of animation not work within the ui-router?
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the JSFiddle AngularJS version 1.2.1 is used, while in the Plunker version 1.4.1 is used. A lot has changed between those two versions.

From the documentation:

> **Are animations run when the application starts?**
>
> No they are not. When an application is bootstrapped Angular will
>   disable animations from running to avoid a frenzy of animations from
>   being triggered as soon as the browser has rendered the screen. For
>   this to work, Angular will wait for two digest cycles until enabling
>   animations. From there on, any animation-triggering layout changes in
>   the application will trigger animations as normal.

In this case you can use the `ng-animate-children` attribute.

For example:

```
<ul ng-animate-children>
    <li class="list-item" ng-repeat="dog in dogs">{{ dog }}</li>
</ul>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/X2DDZUuspOEWEWkADtxw?p=preview

Comment: This is awesome, exactly what I needed 'ng-animate-children'. Thank you for taking the time to help out.